# Можно ли скрывать, а не заново создавать активити?

Tags: java, android

Можно ли создать активити один раз и при нажатии кнопки на главной активити второй активити просто показывать, а не создавать заново?

Comment: Вроде как нет, но я думаю с костылями можно все)

Comment: Я делаю небольшой словарь. И у меня есть меню и в нем пункт "Добавить слово" по нажатию на него открывается новое активити. А если это второе активити уже открыто и я опять нажимаю в меню "Добавить слово", то активити создается еще раз и у меня получается несколько раз создано активити. А можно сделать так: Если допустим я нахожусь во втором активити, то пункт меню "Добавить слово" сделать неактивным?

Comment: Что если скрывать ваш список и показывать форму добавления, во избежания открытия новых активити

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду чтобы во втором активити не отображался данный пункт меню? И такой вопрос. Я новичок в андроид, я правильно понимаю что если нажать клавишу назад, то активити закрывается? или как правильно сказать уничтожается?

Comment: да, у нее будет вызван onDestroy()

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.